# MySQL regular expression replace?

Tags: php, mysql

I know that MySQL does not have a regular expression replace function but I wondered if anyone has written a user defined function that I could use? I know it's not good to just ask for code answers but I am not very skilled in MySQL and was just looking for some help. If there isn't I can accept that.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with the replace functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this site:

http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/

Comment: This sounds great. It requires installing a library to use perl regex but is a valid solution.

Comment: Alternatively, see https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp , which was recommended in the post noted by @tadman.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( 
  replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( 
  replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( 
  replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( 
  replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( 
  replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( 
  replace( replace( replace( replace( replace( 
  replace( replace( replace(

'a~b}c{d`e_f^g\\h[i?j=k;l.m-n,o*p(q&r$s"t u|v]x@y>z<:+)\'%#!\r\f\v\naz\t09\b',

  '~', ''), '}', ''), '{', ''), '`', ''), '_', ''),
  '^', ''), '\\', ''), '[', ''), '?', ''), '=', ''),
  ';', ''), '.', ''), '-', ''), ',', ''), '*', ''),
  '(', ''), '&', ''), '$', ''), '"', ''), ' ', ''),
  '|', ''), ']', ''), '@', ''), '>', ''), '<', ''),
  ':', ''), '+', ''), ')', ''), '\'', ''), '%', ''),
  '#', ''), '!', ''), '\r', ''), '\f', ''), '\v', ''),
  '\n', ''), '\t', ''), '\b', '')
```

Replace

> a~b}c{d`e_f^g\h[i?j=k;l.m-n,o*p(q&r$s"t
>   u|v]x@y>z<:+)\'%#!\r\f\v\naz\t09\b

To

> abcdeghijklmnopqrstuxyzaz09

[MySQL - Regular Expressions & REPLACE](http://plus84ga.blogspot.com/2012/06/mysql-regular-expressions-replace.html)